# Ubuntu 22.04.03 NVIDIA H100 Driver NOT WORKING

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 22.04

H100 is installed on HPE DL560 Gen11 server.
I am trying to install the driver, but it is not recognized properly.
writing down the methods I have tried so far.
PLZ HELP

1. NVIDIA Homepage Driver (.run file) kernerl module 'nvidia.ko' ERROR [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGN0H.png)
2. Installing With CUDA (12.3)
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kcyw.png)
   use CUDA with Driver.. But Same 'nvidia.ko' Error Appear

---

```
 - nvidia-installer.log

 make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-39-generic'
-> done.
-> Kernel module compilation complete.
ERROR: Unable to load the kernel module 'nvidia.ko'.  This happens most frequently when this kernel module was built against the wrong or improperly configured kernel sources, with a version of gcc that differs from the one used to build the target kernel, or if another driver, such as nouveau, is present and prevents the NVIDIA kernel module from obtaining ownership of the NVIDIA device(s), or no NVIDIA device installed in this system is supported by this NVIDIA Linux graphics driver release.

Please see the log entries 'Kernel module load error' and 'Kernel messages' at the end of the file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for more information.
-> Kernel module load error: No such device
-> Kernel messages:
[65404.138694] audit: type=1400 audit(1703032481.789:74): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe" pid=226006 comm="apparmor_parser"
[65404.179546] audit: type=1400 audit(1703032481.833:75): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe//kmod" pid=226006 comm="apparmor_parser"
[65404.179565] audit: type=1400 audit(1703032481.833:76): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-xpdfimport" pid=226014 comm="apparmor_parser"
[65404.179727] audit: type=1400 audit(1703032481.833:77): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-senddoc" pid=226012 comm="apparmor_parser"
[65404.179741] audit: type=1400 audit(1703032481.833:78): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-oosplash" pid=226011 comm="apparmor_parser"
[65404.182328] audit: type=1400 audit(1703032481.833:79): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/man" pid=226009 comm="apparmor_parser"
[65412.032963] kauditd_printk_skb: 20 callbacks suppressed
[65412.032967] audit: type=1400 audit(1703032489.686:100): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/evince" pid=226384 comm="apparmor_parser"
[65412.052046] audit: type=1400 audit(1703032489.706:101): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/evince//sanitized_helper" pid=226384 comm="apparmor_parser"
[65412.052495] audit: type=1400 audit(1703032489.706:102): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/evince//snap_browsers" pid=226384 comm="apparmor_parser"
[65412.054707] audit: type=1400 audit(1703032489.706:103): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/evince-previewer" pid=226384 comm="apparmor_parser"
[65412.055108] audit: type=1400 audit(1703032489.706:104): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/evince-previewer//sanitized_helper" pid=226384 comm="apparmor_parser"
[65412.056295] audit: type=1400 audit(1703032489.710:105): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer" pid=226384 comm="apparmor_parser"
[65781.378193] VFIO - User Level meta-driver version: 0.3
[65781.561750] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 510

[65781.563296] NVRM: This PCI I/O region assigned to your NVIDIA device is invalid:
               NVRM: BAR0 is 0M @ 0x0 (PCI:0000:1a:00.0)
[65781.563309] nvidia: probe of 0000:1a:00.0 failed with error -1
[65781.563378] NVRM: This PCI I/O region assigned to your NVIDIA device is invalid:
               NVRM: BAR0 is 0M @ 0x0 (PCI:0000:49:00.0)
[65781.563395] nvidia: probe of 0000:49:00.0 failed with error -1
[65781.563419] NVRM: The NVIDIA probe routine failed for 2 device(s).
[65781.563420] NVRM: None of the NVIDIA devices were initialized.
[65781.563669] nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered Nvlink Core, major device number 510
ERROR: Installation has failed.  Please see the file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for details.  You may find suggestions on fixing installation problems in the README available on the Linux driver download page at www.nvidia.com.
```

---

3. use ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

It seems work.. But nvidia-smi and settings are not active

---

```
root@fnhai1-ProLiant-DL560-Gen11:/home/fnh-ai1/Desktop# dpkg -l |grep nvidia
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-535:amd64                   535.129.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-common-535                       535.129.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
ii  libnvidia-compute-535:amd64                535.129.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-535:i386                 535.129.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-decode-535:amd64                 535.129.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-decode-535:i386                  535.129.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-encode-535:amd64                 535.129.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-encode-535:i386                  535.129.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-extra-535:amd64                  535.129.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             amd64        Extra libraries for the NVIDIA driver
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-535:amd64                   535.129.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-535:i386                    535.129.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-535:amd64                     535.129.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-gl-535:i386                      535.129.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             i386         NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-535-6.2.0-39-generic  6.2.0-39.40~22.04.1                     amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.2.0-39
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-535-generic-hwe-22.04 6.2.0-39.40~22.04.1                     amd64        Extra drivers for nvidia-535 for the generic-hwe-22.04 flavour
ii  linux-objects-nvidia-535-6.2.0-39-generic  6.2.0-39.40~22.04.1                     amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.2.0-39 (objects)
ii  linux-signatures-nvidia-6.2.0-39-generic   6.2.0-39.40~22.04.1                     amd64        Linux kernel signatures for nvidia modules for version 6.2.0-39-generic
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-535                   535.129.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-driver-535                          535.129.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
ii  nvidia-firmware-535-535.129.03             535.129.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             amd64        Firmware files used by the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-535                   535.129.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-535                   535.129.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
ii  nvidia-prime                               0.8.17.1                                all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                            510.47.03-0ubuntu1                      amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-utils-535                           535.129.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  screen-resolution-extra                    0.18.2                                  all          Extension for the nvidia-settings control panel
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-535              535.129.03-0ubuntu0.22.04.1             amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

---

```
root@fnhai1-ProLiant-DL560-Gen11:/# nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

---

```
root@fnhai1-ProLiant-DL560-Gen11:~# lshw -C display
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: MGA G200eH3
       vendor: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd.
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 03
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=mgag200 latency=0 resolution=1024,768
       resources: irq:17 memory:98000000-98ffffff memory:99b98000-99b9bfff memory:99000000-997fffff memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: 3D controller
       product: GH100 [H100 PCIe]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:1a:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:20a00-209ff iomemory:20800-207ff iomemory:20a00-209ff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: 3D controller
       product: GH100 [H100 PCIe]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:49:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:22200-221ff iomemory:22000-21fff iomemory:22200-221ff
```

---

I performed tasks such as reinstalling the header using uname -r, registering the nouveau blacklist, deleting and reinstalling all installed drivers, but none of them worked.

I am ready to listen to anything you ask.

Comment: Did you totally uninstall the .run version. That should not be used. You then have to reinstall with every kernel update. If wrong version installed you must purge old install(s) first or you get conflicts. https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/nvidia-drivers-installation

Comment: After an Nvidia and a CUDA install of the Nvidia driver, you'd need a purge of \*nvidia\* to really remove everything, then try the update-drivers again.  The 535.29.03 should be fine.  From a system with properly running Nvidia drivers, you can use the Nvidia .run script  or CUDA install, but reject any video driver offers.

Comment: This server and graphics card are newly built, and the currently installed version of Ubuntu 22.04 is the first installed kernel. While carrying out the above work, all drivers were removed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to select another version linux core.

Whean system starting, press ESC, select "advanced options for ubuntu", select 6.2.0-26 for example